# Getting 400 response error for my jmeter request

Tags: jmeter

I am running Jmeter, request as beow. I Am getting Response code: 400
I may be due to the format of the parameters which send for the request. 
I have recoded requested via blazermeter. 
It automatically selected the tick "include equals", no idea what is that too.

[image: HTTP request with Parameter]

Then I got Response code: 400 error as sample request results.
Please consult on this matter

[image: Sample Request Results]

[image: Sample Request]

Answer (score 1):

You're sending your [JSON](https://www.json.org/) payload in a wrong way, you either should move everything into "Value" field of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image: JMeter JSON as Parameter]

Or switch to "Body Data" tab and put your JSON request body there:

[image: JMeter JSON Body Data]

See [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article for more information on how to properly configure JMeter for API testing.

Answer (score 0):

Http code 400 in essence means a bad request. Refer to HTTP codes for details. In your case the request payload appears to be json (make sure that its a valid json) and should be sent as 'Body Data' instead of as 'Parameters' like you've done.

Thanks!